# Likelihood of Change

Tags: verbs, synonyms

Let's say I'm trying to describe two things that change. The first changes often and the second changes less often.

Is there a better word than "volatility" to use in the following scenario? Is it even proper in this use?

1. The first thing has "high volatility"
2. The second thing has "low volatility"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volatile might be more appropriate in technical contexts (e.g. chemistry). On a daily basis, I would use **variability** or **changeability**.

However, if the structure is not fixed, I'd much rather go with something like:

> The first thing is more prone to change.

and

> The second thing is less prone to change.

respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The first changes at a high **frequency** and the other at a low **frequency**.